# Encountering Error : TypeError: OSF.DDA.RichApi.executeRichApiRequestAsync is not a function

Tags: office-js

I have an Microsoft Excel Taskpane Add-in which connects to my Cloud databases and extract the data in the Excel Sheets.The add-in has some filters and based on that output is generated. The add-in works perfectly fine on Office 2016 client with IE/Chrome as default browser. But it gives error on Office Online(On Report Preview) while opening through Google Chrome. On IE, it works fine.

Following is the piece :

## Error Generating Function:-

```
     Excel.run(function (ctx) {

            var StrLocSheetNumber = FunSetSheetName("SheetName");
            if (StrLocSheetNumber != "Sheet1") {
                ctx.workbook.worksheets.add(StrLocSheetNumber).activate();
            }
            else {
                ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet().name = "IssueListing";
                StrLocSheetNumber = "SheetName";
            }

            // Create a proxy object for the active sheet
            var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
            sheet.getRange("C1").values = "Report Header"
            sheet.getRange("C1").format.font.bold = true;
            sheet.getRange("C1").format.font.size = 18
            sheet.getRange("C1").format.horizontalAlignment = "Center";
            sheet.getRange("C1").format.fill.color = "Red";
            sheet.getRange("C1").format.font.color = "White";

            // Queue a command to write the sample 0 data to the worksheet
            var ColumnName = GetExcelColumnName(columncount);
            sheet.getRange("A3:" + ColumnName + (data.length + 3)).values = values;

            var sheetName = StrLocSheetNumber
            var rangeAddress = "A3:" + ColumnName + "3";
            var myRange = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheetName).getRange(rangeAddress);
            myRange.format.fill.color = "Red";
            myRange.format.font.color = "White";
            myRange.format.font.bold = true
            myRange.format.columnWidth = 120;

            // Run the queued-up commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion

            return ctx.sync(); //This is the line where error is seen.

        }).catch(errorHandler);
```

Any ideas/suggestions what could be the problem?

Comment: Just to clarify, what do you mean by "Report Preview"?

Comment: Report Preview means whenever I click on "OK" button to generate the report.

Comment: Apologies for the delay.  I tried to reproduce the issue by pasting in the code you sent.  I am not able to see a repro.  If you want to send (i.e, upload to OneDrive and share) a project, I would be happy to take a look.

Comment: Offhand, I wonder if you somehow have some really old Office.js files cached in Chrome, maybe?... Could you try an Incognito session?

Comment: Hi Michael,I have tried Incognito mode but it doesn't work. You should receive the project soon,

Comment: Shruti, just wanted to follow up, since I don't remember seeing anything on this.  If it's still relevant, just let me know...

Comment: Hi Michael..Well this is sorted out.But facing another issues in opening hyperlink.I am posting another question on that front. Thanks for the help!!